# How to fix "Type 'BaseCtor' is not assignable to type 'T'" while using generics with default params

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create an instance by using createInstance with generics as below.It works well when I pass two arguments to function. If the function invoked without Ctor which is the second param, it provide BaseCtor as default. In this case, it throw an error like "Type 'BaseCtor' is not assignable to type 'T'". What should I do to fix whatever arguments it is?

```
class BaseCtor {}
const createInstance = function createInstance<T extends BaseCtor>(
  options: object = {},
  Ctor: {new (): T} = BaseCtor
): T {
  return new Ctor();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might already know this but it might be worthwhile to walk through it:

The type parameter of a generic function is resolved by the caller, not the implementer.  Furthermore, callers are allowed to manually specify this value by using an explicit type in angle brackets, as long as the parameters passed conform to this.  So all the following are valid ways to call `createInstance()`:

```
class Foo extends BaseCtor {
  prop = "me";
}

const i1 = createInstance({ a: "okay" }, Foo); // Foo
const i2 = createInstance<Foo>({ a: "okay" }, Foo); // Foo
const i3 = createInstance({ a: "okay" }); // BaseCtor
const i4 = createInstance<Foo>({ a: "okay" }); // Foo
```

Does `i4` surprise you?  In this case the caller has manually specified `T` is `Foo`, but passed only one parameter in.  The compiler will use the default constructor value `BaseCtor`, but `BaseCtor` does not construct `Foo` instances!  That's what the error you're getting is all about.  It's saying that `BaseCtor` cannot be guaranteed to be assignable to `T`, since all we know is that `T` *extends* `BaseCtor`.

---

Clearly you want some way so that a caller is *unable* to specify some subtype of `BaseCtor` when using just one argument.  Probably the easiest tool to accomplish this is the [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).  Provide two distinct call signatures and one implementation, like this:

```
// call signature: two args
function createInstance<T extends BaseCtor>(
  options: object,
  Ctor: { new (): T }
): T;
// call signature: zero or one arg
function createInstance(options?: object): BaseCtor;

// implementation signature
function createInstance(
  options: object = {},
  Ctor: { new (): BaseCtor } = BaseCtor
): BaseCtor {
  return new Ctor();
}
```

or equivalently (matching your code more closely):

```
const createInstance = function createInstance(
  options: object = {},
  Ctor: { new (): BaseCtor } = BaseCtor
): BaseCtor {
  return new Ctor();
} as {
  <T>(options: object, Ctor: new () => T): T;
  (options?: object): BaseCtor;
};
```

Now `i4` is not possible and the rest of the calls behave the way you want:

```
const i1 = createInstance({ a: "okay" }, Foo); // Foo
const i2 = createInstance<Foo>({ a: "okay" }, Foo); // Foo
const i3 = createInstance({ a: "okay" }); // BaseCtor
const i4 = createInstance<Foo>({ a: "okay" }); // error! expected 2 args, got 1
```

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDCAXA9gJ2gbwFDWgCNEAFDNAB2gF5oAiATwQjoG5cBfXXYNAOwgpowDAjAoEASQEowfYAhrQAZgFd5KAJb9ho8VJlyFACnzRKW-hABc5wgCsEwIbWwcANGdSZb2aHwQAd2hjAEpbeAhkdCwOJUjozFxwuERvLDwCURRVDD5-IOh0sPY4yBwzAB4AFQA+YwttAVs0BycUdyKY2wDgsJpa6GqU6vYCBopLAQB+FrbnFIT00vYecChoADE0NGgEAA8JPgATGCWYioIKcipaOgBbBDZObl4ZaE0ARiURMQlpQRGBDGPxgWx0NAAazADDo0A8Wx2oVY0AA9KjEWgeFYhJoAEw-PT-QzyBCVbZoeqg8FQmFwhEU5FojEU7HvTQAZkJfwMgNJIOgYPotNh8KZ6NSUXSbMEHwALNz9ADZKTyTsqYKadDRRxxRiEBhyBgAIR7fYUdoIY7QAlgDAAcwgnXtaCEn1wQA)

Comment: yeah! It works as you say, thank you for your time!